Why I have an empty list in the output?
this is my exam that I must know why I have an empty list when I want to start moving from index -1 to index -4?
thanks a lot:)
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(My_list[1:4]) # output is [2, 3, 4]
print(my_list[-1:-4]) # output is []


By default, slices begin at the starting index and proceed forward in the list until the ending index is reached.  If the ending index is smaller than the starting index, it will not infer that the direction ought to be backwards. It still defaults to forwards.
